# Mounting onprem datastore to Azure Databricks dbfs

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-databricks

I am looking for a solution to mount local storage which is on on premise hadoop cluster that can be used with databricks to mount onto dbfs:/// directly instead of loading to azure blob storage and then mounting it to databricks. Any advice here would be helpful. Thank You

I am in research side and still have not figured a way to come up with solution. I am not sure even if its possible with out azure storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, mounting on Prem datastore to Azure Databricks not supported.

> You can try these alternative methods:

**Method 1:**

Connecting local files on a remote data bricks spark cluster access local file with DBFS. Refer this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect).

**Method 2:**

Alternative use azure [Databricks CLI or REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/) and push local data to a location on DBFS, where it can be read into Spark from within a Databricks notebook.

For more information refer this [Blog](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/storage-options-and-file-manipulation-commands-in-azure-databricks/) by Vikas Verma